# How to avoid type erasue in JAXB, MOXY implementation while marshalling?

Tags: xml, soap, jaxb, moxy, type-erasure

**I have to marshall following class ;**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SYSMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Message<T> {

    @XmlPath("Personel")
    private Personel personel;

    @XmlPath("AccountType")
    private T accountType;

    ...
```

So in production I set generic Account type class with some object called "DebitAccount"
I have to use generic type because debitAccount will change many times.

```
Message<DebitAccount> msg = new Msg<>();
DebitAccount dAccount= new DebitAccount();
msg.setAccountType(dAccount);
```

and when I marshalled class Message, I got the following xml result as account type; 
    ...
    org.demo.blabla.DebitAccount@123123
    ...

**In DebitAccount class;**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DebitAccount{

    @XmlPath("ID")
    private String id;

    @XmlPath("Visa")
    private String visaNo;
```

I figured out this is happening because of Type erasure. Moxy just cant simply understand that my object is DebitAccount. So it treats object as string. How can I make moxy understand my composite object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind DebitAccount class to the same XML context of Message class using @XmlSeeAlso annotation. You can list multiple classes with curly braces. When using generic types (T or ?), you have to specify which classes are part of the same context.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "SYSMessage")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({DebitAccount.class})
public class Message<T> { ... }
```

Comment: I tried the solution you suggest and it worked! Thanks for answer.
I add DebitAccount and other classes in @XmlSeeAlso annotation. 
@XmlSeeAlso({DebitAccount.class, A.class, B.class}) etc.